# How to bind this context to a self-invoking function?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get `this` from inside a self-invoking function like this

```
// this is defined here and works just fine.
(function(){
    this.doSomething()
    // this is undefined here.
}/*tried .bind(this) here, but it didn't seem to help*)();
```

The actual function is a bit more complex, but here is the simplified example of the problem.

How do I pass `this` context to a self-invoking function like the one above besides `var self = this` outside the function then addressing it from inside as `self.doSomething()`?

Comment: `(function(self){
    self.doSomething();
})(this);`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the .bind() methods works on self invoking functions. so my work around that is this...

`var that = this;
(function(that){
    that.doSomething()
})(that);`

name 'this' to something else like 'self' or in my example 'that' because if you use 'this' keyword in the self invoking function it will refer the 'this' to the self invoking function. So just pass the variable through to the self invoking function through the parameters. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The way you tried should work just fine. I created a small wrapper function called `test` to demonstrate:

```
function test() {
    (function(){
        this.doSomething()
    }.bind(this))(); // bind this here
}

test.call({
    doSomething: function() {
        console.log('hello world');
    }
}); // call test with a dummy object as this
```

Comment: Seems like I have an issue with the multiply-nested functions, not in the piece of code I shared.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
(function () {
    this.doSomething();
}).call(yourThis);
```

and if you really want to use `bind`

```
(function () {
    this.doSomething();
}).bind(yourThis)();
```